Is the given set Borel measurable?
Let
$$S=\left \{\sum _{i \geq 1}\frac{x_i}{10^i} \in [0,1]: x_i\in\{0,1,...,9\}\text{ and} \sum _{i \geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{x_i}}{i}\text{ converges}\right \}$$, is the set Borel measurable?
Here's my original idea which might be terribly wrong: (added)
I tried to define $f_n=\sum _{i\leq n}\frac{(-1)^{x_i}}{i}$ on $\mathbb{R}$,
where even if $x$ has 2 decimal expressions I will use the one with no tailing 9's, in that case $f_n$
has countably many discontinuities, which is Borel measurable. Then the set $S$ is the preimage of the limit of $f_n$
of $\mathbb{R}$, where the limit of Borel measurable is Borel measurable implies $S$ is Borel measurable. But I think there has to be some error because the fact that the limit of $f_n$
may be infinity may cause some results to fail but I don't know which results.

what have you tried so far?

@user140776 I tried to define $f_n=\sum _{i\leq n}(-1)^{x_i}/i$ on $\mathbb{R}$ where even if x has 2 decimal expressions I will use the one with no tailing 9's, in that case $f_n$ has countably many discontinuities, which is Borel measurable. Then the set S is the preimage of the limit of $f_n$ of R, where the limit of Borel measurable is Borel measurable implies S is Borel measurable. But I think there has to be some error because the fact that the limit of $f_n$ may be infinity may cause some results to fail but I don't know which results.

Just a friendly tip, you will probably get more responses if you put your work in the original post rather than in the comments

Your original idea seems ok to me.

Yes.  General reason: Explicit definition of a non-Borel set is much harder to do than this!

@GEdgar You mean it's difficult to explicitly construct a non-Borel measurable set?

First note that
$$\left\{\sum _{i \geq 1}\frac{x_i}{10^i} \in [0,1]: x_i\in\{0,1,...,9\}\right\}=[0,1]$$
because this is simply the base ten (decimal) representation of the real numbers from 0 to 1. We could also write $0.x_1x_2x_2x_3...$ in place of $\sum _{i \geq 1}\frac{x_i}{10^i}$, for example
$$0.333...=\sum _{i \geq 1}\frac{3}{10^i}$$
Next notice that your set, S, is  simply  all of the real numbers from 0 to 1 whose base ten representation $0.x_1x_2x_3...$ satisfies the condition that
$$\sum _{i \geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{x_i}}{i}\text{ converges}$$
Now you have a sum that looks  very much like the  random harmonic series

Is random harmonic series Borel measurable function of sequences?

Hint:
Every real number $x\in(0,1)$ has a unique decimal representation $\sum^\infty_{n=1}r_n(x)10^{-n}$ such that $\sum_nr_n=\infty$.

Show that for any $n$, $x\mapsto r_n(x)$ is measurable from $(0,1)$ to $\mathbb{R}$ (or $\mathbb{N}$ if you prefer).
For each $N\in\mathbb{N}$, show that the map $x\mapsto S_N(x)=\sum^N_{n=1}(-1)^{r_n(x)}\frac1n$ is measurable.
Show that the set $C=\{x\in(0,1): S_N(x),\, \text{converges}\}$ is measurable:
$$C=\bigcap_{\ell\geq1}\bigcup_{k}\bigcap_{n\geq k}\bigcap_{m\geq k}\{x\in(0,1): |S_n(x)-S_m(x)|<\frac1\ell\}$$.


Is following correct? 1. $r_n$ has at most finitely many jump/removable discontinuities, so Borel measurable. 2. $(-1)^{r_n}$ has at most finitely many jump/removable discontinuities too, so $S_N$ their sum is Borel measurable too. 3. The set at which a sequence of Borel measurable functions converge is also Borel measurable (which I've seen in past papers before)

By the way, do you think my original idea (now in post) is wrong?

@HIH: it is easier if you slice the interval $(0,1)$ in pieces of length $10^{-k}$. For example, ${x:r_1(x)=1}=(1/10,2/10]$.

@HIH: I used a similar idea for binary expansions here. You can modify the ideas for decimal expansion.
